# Строгое сравнение в min-width и max-width

Tags: css, media-queries

Если одновременно использовать `@media (max-width: 1000px)` и `@media (min-width: 1000px)`, то при ширине ровно 1000px будут выполняться оба правила

Если использовать `@media (max-width: 1000px)` и `@media (min-width: 1001px)`, то при масштабе в 1,25 и ширине 1251px не будет выполняться ни одно из этих правил (т.к. 1251/1,25=1000,8)

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы одно правило выполнялось при ширине **меньшей либо равной** 1000px, а другое выполнялось при ширине **строго большей** 1000px?

Comment: Тогда возможно вас удовлетворит оператор **not**? `@media not (max-width: 1000px)`

Comment: Да, это помогло, спасибо) Хотя по каким-то причинам `@media not (max-width: 1000px)` у меня не сработало, а сработало `@media not all and (max-width: 1000px)`

Comment: класс! оформил ответом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задачу решает использование оператора отрицания для второго медиа-запроса.

```
@media not all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    /* ... */
}
```